# Changes/Watch API cannot be scoped to individual drive?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to set up my application to receive webhook calls when a change is made to a user's drive.  Code currently looks like this:

```
        var service = GetDriveService("myemail@example.com");

        var channel = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Channel
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Address = "https://myapplication.com/notifications",
            Type = "web_hook",
            Token = "mypersonaldrive"
        };

        ChangesResource.WatchRequest req = service.Changes.Watch(channel, "920");

        req.SupportsTeamDrives = false;
        req.IncludeTeamDriveItems = false;
        req.RestrictToMyDrive = true;

        var newChannel = await req.ExecuteAsync();
```

The channel is created, however the application is notified for every single change my user makes, even if it's in a team drive.  Given that I'm restricting this to my drive, shouldn't I only receive callbacks for changes to file that are actually in my drive?

Any advice on how to make this work?

In the notifications, the ResourceUri is:

```
[X-Goog-Resource-URI, https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?includeCorpusRemovals=false&includeRemoved=true&includeTeamDriveItems=false&pageSize=100&pageToken=920&restrictToMyDrive=true&spaces=drive&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json]
```

How am I supposed to know what this user actually changed?